# Optimising MySQL Script

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have started a new job and they are using MySQL as their main DB.

I am more use to MSSQL and was wondering if the following statement can be optimised as it's taking 10 minutes!

Thank you in advance for any help anyone can offer.

```
SELECT 
CAST(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:00') 
AS DATETIME) AS 'Date', 
COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM 
db 
WHERE 
created_at BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 5 HOUR AND NOW() 
AND status = 'Accepted' 
GROUP BY CAST(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:00') 
AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: You have an index on created_at? Or (created_at,status)? Also, you can lose the casting in the GROUP BY.

Comment: Yes I have an index on both the created at and status. I have just removed the casting so it only shows... GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:00') now the script will not run.

Comment: You have to remove the last line. You could try dropping the individual indices and replacing with a composite. Other than that, I can't see much room for improvement - but maybe others will have better ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I would not know where to start with dropping indices. I will have a look on Google though so thanks. Paul

Comment: `ALTER TABLE my_table DROP INDEX x; ALTER TABLE my_table DROP INDEX y; ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX (x,y);`

Answer (score 0):

No clue why you do the cast within the select or the group by but replace the last line by:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i')
```

If that doesn't help much, add 'EXPLAIN ' before that command, check the output. If you can't figure it out with the explain-prefix, post it here so someone can give you advice on indexes.

Answer (score 0):

An index `(status, created_at)` will optimise the `WHERE` part of this query (constants before ranges).

Your grouping seems to indicate you want to group by the minute of `created_at`. Creating a generated column based on this expression and appending this to the index would assist the `GROUP BY` part of this clause (and the `GROUP BY` should refer to this generated column rather than an expression).

```
alter table db add minute bigint unsigned as (to_seconds(created_at) div 60),
                 add index status_created_at_min (status, created_at, minute);
```

And the resulting query:

```
SELECT 
CAST(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:00') 
AS DATETIME) AS 'Date', 
COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM 
db 
WHERE 
created_at BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 5 HOUR AND NOW() 
AND status = 'Accepted' 
GROUP BY minute;
```

Comment: This and drop the "CAST( AS DATETIME)". The result is returning strings and the "DATE_FORMAT()" already gives you the desired format, so the casting just slows it down for no reason. And just an advice in general: use bracelets around "x between y and z". It makes it easier to read and some database settings might cause troubles when there are no bracelets.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to speed it up some, because it will take care of the `WHERE`:

```
INDEX(status, created_at)   -- in this order
```

If you create a "generated" column (as danblack suggests), then carry it a step further by using *only* the generated column in the query and the index.  That way this becomes a "covering" index so the query is performed entirely in the index:

```
INDEX(status, minute)   -- in this order
```

If that is not enough...

Large tables with "reports" often benefit from creating and maintaining "Summary Table(s)".  Unlike some other vendors, there is no builtin mechanism for doing this.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) .